# Typescript concat string to draw Html

Tags: angular, string, typescript, concatenation

In Angular2 v4 I have an array with multiple items. For example:

```
const array = ['1', '2', '3'];
array.forEach(h => {
  this.htmlhistory.concat('hello <br>');
});
```

the `htmlhistory` item is a string

and in my html component I have this:

```
<div>
  {{ this.htmlhistory }}
</div>
```

So the result have to be:

```
<div>
  hello <br>
  hello <br>
  hello <br>
</div>
```

BUT this doesn't works... What I'm doing wrong?
Is there anothes solution without using `*ngFor`?

I need a solution in the component.ts file ... not in the html file

Please help

Comment: What does it do? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<div>
  {{ this.htmlhistory }}
</div>
```

Use this

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlhistory">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render HTML in your component you are expected to use `[innerHTML]="htmlhistory"` not `{{}}` syntax.

Here is a quick [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnsyct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts), in case you needed it.